# How to create a dataset with variables that are duplicates in SAS

Tags: sas, duplicates

I have removed duplicates from a dataset using the nodupkey feature, but want to compare the deleted duplicates to the first observation that is kept.

```
proc sort data=matchedfile dupout=deletedduplicate nodupkey 
out=dedupedfile;
by ID;
run;
```

We need a datasets that combines all observations that are duplicates, the removed duplicates in the dupout file and the observation with the same id in the dedupedfile.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't sufficiently clear on what you want, and it seems like more of a request for code than is appropriate here.  Have you looked at, for example, `PROC COMPARE`?  And what do you mean by "compare", anyway...  and what your data looks like is key here, are there always just 1 duplicated row or is it 10 duplicates sometimes??

Comment: I was trying to get to a final data set that would have all of those lines of data which have a duplicate ID so I could export to excel and just eyeball them, see why of my IDs are duplicates.  I do know from the dupout file that most of the time there is just one duplicated row, but sometimes it is more than one duplicate.

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this than eyeballing in excel. In a data step, it's easy to output the unique records, duplicate records, etc to different data sets. With a little work, you can also answer questions like "when there are two records with a duplicate key, are the values for all non-key variables identical?"  If that sounds useful, suggest you start a new question along the lines of "when cleaning data that may have duplicates, how can i identify records that ..."

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that you want the 'not removed' row with the 'removed' rows, you can use the `NOUNIKEY` option added in SAS 9.3.  It does the opposite of `NODUPKEY` - only keeps records that are NOT unique - and removes the unique records.  You can have those removed unique records just discarded (if you will, separately, do a different query to get them) or you can use `UNIQUEOUT` to put them in a dataset.

```
proc sort data=have out=dups nounikey uniqueout=nodups;
  by whatever;
run;
```

See [PROC SORT documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p02bhn81rn4u64n1b6l00ftdnxge.htm) for more details.